# D deprecated class allocators

Tags: d

Why are class allocators and deallocators deprecated in D2?

And, another minor question, how are implemented references in D?

I somewhere saw keyword ref, but I don't know, how is references realised.

Have D somethink like global handle table and references are only indexes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class allocators and deallocators are deprecated since with them, the user doesn't really know what is going on, leading to memory safety or leak issues. Typically, D programs assume `new X` works with the garbage collector, and with the allocator being changed, it might not, leading to confusion.

Instead, if you want to change allocation, you should provide a factory function so it is clear that this is done differently. Together with private constructors, you can force the use of your custom function.

A reference is implemented as a pointer. When you write `void foo(ref int b) { b = 10; }` in D, it is as if you wrote `void foo(int* b) { *b = 10; }` in C. A pointer is a memory address represented as a number. It points to the object's location and allows changing the object through it. Copying pointers is as cheap as copying regular integers, so passing them to functions is pretty efficient.

Comment: Thats very sad. In C++, programers know how its working, but in D not. It will be removed in future (class allocators and dealocators)? Like scope keyword?

Comment: How I make factory function (it's a simple function?)? How call constructor on address?

Comment: The scope keyword isn't going away, there's just one very specific use of it right now that is deprecated - using it on a class declaration to put it on the stack. It is deprecated because escaping that reference will lead to memory corruption. BUT, scope is also supposed to prohibit escaping the reference, so if we ever actually implement that, the stack optimization can come back. The other uses of scope btw, e.g. `scope(exit)`, aren't going anywhere.

Comment: For the factory function, just do a regular function or static method that allocates the memory however you want, then constructs the class using emplace: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#emplace

Here's a quick example: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/malloc.d note that I did *not* make the ctor private there, since that actually breaks emplace. If you want a private constructor, you'll have to the emplacing yourself too instead of using the library function.

Comment: A difference between C++ and D in this regard btw is that C++ always assumes the programmer is managing things manually. You *always* pair news with deletes in C++. In D, you almost *never* use delete (indeed, its usage is deprecated since it can invalidate references, leading to memory corruption, and can limit potential GC designs).

So, if you change the allocator to something that must be properly deleted or copied when going out of scope, nobody is going to expect that in D. In C++, you are mindful of those details anyway so it isn't as surprising.

Comment: And, if I want to implement emplace on my own, how I call constructor on address?

Comment: You can see the full implementation in the source: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/conv.d#L3888 in short though, you copy the initial contents to the memory (typeid(Class).init), then cast it to the class type, then call obj.__ctor(args);

Comment: Thanks for support Adam. I have last question, where can I found this detailed information? I read language reference on dlang.org, but there isnt this kind of informations (for example, __ctor()). First, I want to try write bootloader with D, but I'm scared of this...I need detailed documentation abou GC and how to not integrate it to binary, but...there is only basic informations :(

Comment: I always just go to the source code... it takes a little while to get to know its layout, but then it is fairly easy to read. When you download dmd, the complete source for compiler and runtime and std library are in the dmd2/src folder.